# How do I incorporate HTML code into my Java scriptlet method? (JSP)

Tags: java, html, jsp, scriptlet

I am trying to include HTML inside a java scriptlet method. A pseudocode example:

```
<%! public void doSomething() {
        %>
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <%   
} %>
```

The above example doesn't work because the compiler thinks that the method ends right after it's declared.

Is there an alternate way?

Comment: Have a look at out.println(...)

Comment: The above is just an example; I know I could just do something like out.println(..), but I'm trying to learn how I would add html to my scriptlet method

Comment: Have a look at out.println(...). But you really don't want to do this anyway, regardless of how you think you want to.

Comment: That is the ONLY way you would add HTML to your scriptlet method, but echoing @DaveNewton that's a BAD IDEA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you really shouldn't be using scriptlets and especially shouldn't be defining methods in scriptlets.

Nevertheless, you can print HTML with `out.print()` too, and even in a method defined in a scriptlet. You will run into the issue that in your declaration block you don't have access to `out` unless you declare a global JspWriter and set it to `out` lower down in your scriptlet, like below:

```
<%! 
JspWriter jout = null;
public void doSomething() 
{
   jout.print("<p>Hello World</p>");
}
%>
<%
jout = out;
doSomething();
%>
```